# configuring the parsing logic in a XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

My java application gets xml feed from multiple sources, though most of them follow  same standard, there are few cases of exception for eg: feed X will send a value in tag a and feed Y may send the same value in tag b.

Just wanted to know if we have any xml parser or an engine wherein we can configure in some xml or somewhere on how one particular feed has to be parsed.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: do you wish to describe/validate the xml dialects from your feeds, do you want to normalize the feeds into a common format, or do you need a shrink-wrapped mapping from the xml feeds to some Java data structure ? Also, pls show some data and your efforts.

Comment: Ultimately I need to map the xml data to a java data structure. If I have to write code for above said inconsistent xml structure, I will end up in putting lots of unnecessary if/else conditions, different code for each feed, code wont be generic. So I was thinking of some way in which I can configure few of this dynamic tag in some xml/xslt  and this xml can be used while parsing the feed.

Comment: `xslt` means `XSL Transformations` - you can try to normalize the xml variant to a common denominator with a xslt processor. This presupposes that your data is syntactically valid xml and makes most sense if the structures are 'close' (ie. differing by some tag names only, `a` vs. `b` in your case). You may also want to look into SAX parsers, though it might be overkill. I do not know about  direct xml->java data structures mapping tools/frameworks

Comment: Do you know when reading/accessing a feed which element or tag it contains? If you know that then it is easy normalizing the ones with e.g. `b` utilizing XSLT to replace the `b` elements with `a` elements. You can implement that with a few lines of XSLT and you can even chain the XSLT in the Java word into SAX with `SAXTransformerFactory.html` and its methods `newTransformerHandler` or `newXMLFilter`